# How to insert a php variable in an sql query? Mistake in my query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I wrote this simple code to delete a blog from the sql table. But its giving an error

```
Could not delete data: Unknown column '$qid' in 'where clause'
```

Cant understand why. `$qid` is the variable while just `qid` is the column name and its giving me this error.

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db('trial1');
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
function check_login(){
        return 12;
}
$return_array = array();
if( check_login()!=NULL){
    $qid =1;
    $sql='DELETE FROM blog_post WHERE qid = $qid';
    $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
    if (!$retval){
        die('Could not delete data: ' . mysql_error());
        $return_array["success"] = 0; //If deletion unsuccessful
        echo json_encode($return_array);
    }
    else{
        $return_array["success"]=1; //If deletion successful 
        echo json_encode($return_array);
    }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: just try with $sql='DELETE FROM blog_post WHERE qid = "'.$qid.'"';

Answer (score 2):

Variables will not be parsed under single quotes. Enclose the SQL query under double quotes `"`.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM `blog_post` WHERE `qid` = $qid"; //<-- Like this.
```

---

This (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of `PHP 5.5.0`, and will be removed in the future. Instead, **Prepared Statements** of [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`PDO_MySQL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) extension should be used to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: Thanx a lot. Working now. Never knew that this was important. Seems I always used double quotes and first time used single quotes and this happened :P

Comment: @user3481478, Glad its working , but please see the disclaimer. You need to switch to a new database API. Currently, you are using a deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your input in the sql with single quotes :

```
 $sql="DELETE FROM `blog_post` WHERE `qid` = '$qid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Very first you need to make sure you have a column name **qid** in table.

Then try:

```
$sql='DELETE FROM blog_post WHERE qid ='.$qid;
```